# SQL Count within MAX select

Tags: sql, sql-server, crosstab

I need to crosstab some data from my sample table with counts of the crosstabed values.
In the table below I am displaying a few records for two participants, I need to crosstab this information with grouping on the PID.

Here is some data from the table:

```
PID   SAMPLE_TYPE  SAMPLE_VOLUME
PID1  PLASMA_EDT   250
PID1  PLASMA_EDT   1200
PID1  PLASMA_EDT   1000
PID1  PLASMA_EDT   1000
PID1  PLASMA_EDT   1000
PID1  SER          500
PID1  SER          500
PID1  SER          1000
PID2  PLASMA_EDT   250
PID2  PLASMA_EDT   1200
PID2  PLASMA_EDT   1000
PID2  PLASMA_EDT   500
PID2  PLASMA_EDT   1000
PID2  SER          500
PID2  SER          1000
PID2  SER          1000
```

What I need as an output is the following:

```
PID   PLA_250  PLA_500  PLA_1000  PLA1200  SER_500  SER_1000  
PID1  1        0        3         1        2        1
PID2  1        1        2         1        1        2
```

So I tried with the following but come up with error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

.

```
SELECT  S.C_PID AS PID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '250' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'PLA_250',
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '500' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'PLA_500',
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '1000' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'PLA_1000',
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '1200' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'PLA_1200',
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'SER' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '500' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'SER_500',
        MAX(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'SER' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '1000' THEN COUNT(CONCAT (S.SAMPLE_TYPE, S.SAMPLE_VOLUME)) ELSE '' END) AS 'SER_1000'
FROM    SAMPLE S
WHERE   S.C_PID IN ('PID1','PID2')
        AND S.SAMPLE_TYPE IN ('PLASMA_EDT','SER')
GROUP BY S.C_PID
```

How should I be tackling this?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '250' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'PLA_250',
```

Comment: Thank you dnoeth, that returns what I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify those aggregations

For example:

```
...
COUNT(CASE WHEN S.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'PLASMA_EDT' AND S.SAMPLE_VOLUME = '250' THEN 1 END) AS [PLA_250],
...
```